Usual isomorphism between Cl(0,2) and quaternions is not correct
I have seen multiple times that an isomorphism between Cl(0,2) and quaternions is e1 -> i, e2 -> j, e12 -> k. However, it seems to me that it is not correct because it does not satisfy all three realations ij=k, jk=i, and ki = j (It seems to me that there is some kind of handeness problem.)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Not sure why you think there's an issue. $$ij = e_1e_2 = k,$$$$ik = e_1e_1e_2 = -e_2 = -j,$$$$jk = e_2e_1e_2 = -e_1e_2e_2 = e_1 = i.$$

You are right. I was forgetting that the vectors square to -1 instead to +1. Thanks a lot !

Sorry I can not upvote, but it is my first post and the system does not allow me.

@LuisVielva You should be able to mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark below the upvote/downvote arrows.
